# Manipulating objects in AR with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, webcam, augmented-reality, motion-detection

I have for a really long time been searching for a tutorial for an augmented reality application where the users can rotate and\or move a rendered 3D object with hand movements. I have found a few example applications of this, but none with viewable sourcecode, or in any way allowing me to change the models loaded.

What I need is either a working application that I can tamper with in AS3, or a decent tutorial for creating this kind of motion tracking. (I have been able to create a motion tracking application in itself, but not as an AR application where the models loaded are the ones affected by my movement.)

I am rather new to augmented reality programming, and only have the basics of marker based AR down, but I really don't need anything fancy, nor do I particularly need to understand the cone 100% (though obviously it would be better if I did). I just need it to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is FLAR toolkit.

http://www.libspark.org/wiki/saqoosha/FLARToolKit/en

Here's a tutorial: http://mlab.taik.fi/mediacode/archives/1939

Enjoy